# How to retrieve values in select tag within the radio button using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I have the following html radio tags. Basiclly, it has 3 radio button and the user can only pick one and I want the jquery code to pick up the value from the checked radio.

There is 3 radio button, one for all day, one for N/A and one for time. And once user click time, it can selected the time between 12:00 to 20:00 in the  tag.

I know that using `.val()` for extract the value for the other two options, but I am figuring out how to extract the values on the times when the time radio button is selected.

I am using Meteor framework for this project, but i guess this is a jQuery question.

html

```
<tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="mon" value="all">all day</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="mon" value="time">between 
        <select name="firstTime">
            <option>Time</option>
            <option value="12">12:00</option>
            <option value="13">13:00</option>
            <option value="14">14:00</option>
            <option value="15">15:00</option>
            <option value="16">16:00</option>
            <option value="17">17:00</option>
            <option value="18">18:00</option>
            <option value="19">19:00</option>
            <option value="20">20:00</option>
        </select>
        to 
        <select name="secondTime">
            <option>Time</option>
            <option value="12">12:00</option>
            <option value="13">13:00</option>
            <option value="14">14:00</option>
            <option value="15">15:00</option>
            <option value="16">16:00</option>
            <option value="17">17:00</option>
            <option value="18">18:00</option>
            <option value="19">19:00</option>
            <option value="20">20:00</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="mon" value="n/a">N/A</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('checkbox').checked` returns `true` if it is checked. Put different `id` to your checkboxs

Comment: is there a way to get the time as well from the <select> tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6ubps15c/1/)**

```
$("input[name=mon]").on("change", function(){
    if(this.value=="time"){
        alert("First Time : " + $('select[name="firstTime"] option:selected').text());
        alert("Second Time : "+$('select[name="secondTime"] option:selected').text());
    }

});
```

---

**UPDATE**

For this **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6ubps15c/2/)** I am trying to get values on button click:

```
$('.getVal').on('click',function(){
    var selectedoption=$("input[name=mon]:checked").val().trim();
    if(selectedoption=="time"){
        var dispValue="First Time : " + $('select[name="firstTime"] option:selected').text()+ " and Second Time : "+$('select[name="secondTime"] option:selected').text();
        $('.dispSelected').text(dispValue); 
    }
    else
    {
        $('.dispSelected').text(selectedoption + " has been selected"); 
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there some sort of get value type of method instead of change in the form field?

Comment: Cos I want it to be once users submit the form, it extract the value either, N/A, All day or some time between?

Comment: @TomChan. Unclear. Can you elaborate pls!! If I understood it properly, on submit of form you need to check whether this is time is selected and if yes then get the select values right?

Comment: Yes, so I get the information so either the user is avaliable all day or Not avaliable (N/A) or free between certain time?

Comment: @Tomchan .. Updated answer.. check and let me know!!

Comment: Thanks, it s correct, now I just figure how to implement it in Meteorjs!!

Comment: exactly!! :) Anyways Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: just want to ask, how come this work? if(selectedoption=="time")

Comment: I am storing the selected radio button's value using `var selectedoption=$("input[name=mon]:checked").val().trim();` in `selectedoption` and if you see html you will find a value attribute inside your radio button!!

Answer (score 1):

You can get their value when they change, for example:

```
jQuery("input[type=radio]").on("change", function(){
  alert(this.value); //Will show the value of the selected radio
});
```

For getting the `select` values, you can get them, for example, when the `selects` change or when the `radios` change. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu0yu0tb/).

Comment: and the selected time?

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your question. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values when the form is submitted use the following code:

```
$('form').on('submit', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();//this holds all the form data
    ......
});
```

But to ensure that times are only included when the `time` radio button is selected you need the following code:

```
$('input[name=mon]').on('change', function() {
    $('select[name=firstTime], select[name=secondTime]').prop('disabled', this.value != 'time');
});
```